# PHP - MySQL Security Issue?

Tags: php, mysql, security, include, require

Just wondering is this could be a potential security problem with MySQL and PHP:

I have a connect.php file on a server, if someone used `require(http://myurl.com/connect.php/);`, would this allow them access to my database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but for additional security, it's best to keep your sensitive files outside of the web root, in case a misconfiguration of your webserver breaks PHP and exposes it as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

No, that would not allow them to connect to your database. When they require your connect.php over Internet, they get what is produced by this php script as output. In your case, your php script (connect.php) probably produces nothing as output (it just connects to db and terminates.

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP variables are not accessible client side. For example a file like this

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

The `$con` variable would not be accessible publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. If "someone" does `require(http://myurl.com/connect.php/);` from his server (and has the inclusion via http enabled, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), then his server connects to your server and fetches the **interpreted output** of your connect.php.

Answer (score -3):

If you have 'server side include' enabled - yes.

Read about `allow_url_include` directive: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: @BaBL86 Could you please elaborate on why you think it possible?

Comment: @user2370460 You need to print PHP code with logins and passwords in this file by direct URL. If someone know this path (and chinese scanner already know it) - they can access your database.

Comment: @BaBL86 Accessing a file that just sets variables, i.e. `<?php $password = 'test'; ?>` in the browser will result in a blank page, not a printout of sensitive data.